# Default controller is not getting called when Custom middleware is injected using ApplicationBuilder Map in .net core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I trying to add specific middleware for a specific path as follow. The Middleware is getting called but the controller is not getting called and API returns 404 not found.

```
 app.Map("/api/tokenize", subApp =>
        {
            subApp.UseRequestTokenizationMiddleware();
        });
```

What code/configuration change required so that controller is also get called along with custom middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that in .Net Core you can specify the "path" a request takes.  In the Configure method of Startup add a line

```
app.UseRequestTokenizationMiddleware();
```

and make sure that it only processes requests that are pertinent.  Then the next handler in the chain will get the request.  The last thing in Configure is usually

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Here's a good start [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: There are different different groups of path dependent middlewares  and it's not best practice to add each and every possible path condition inside every middlewares.

Comment: Of course not.  In theory, each handler, in turn, will look at the request and say "None of my business... NEXT" unless it should take action (auth/identity/etc.) It does not care about what other handlers exist nor what they do.  "Separation of Concerns"